# How to add resizer to textarea in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, resize, textarea, resizable

How to add resizer to textarea in IE the same as in Chrome and Firefox?

`jQuery.resizable()` won't work for me.

Comment: Check out my griphandle plugin I made a while back for inspiration: https://github.com/PeeHaa/gripHandler

Comment: Maybe this is useful info: Chrome and Firefox's textarea resize functionality is native. This means you will have to search for and try out plugins for Internet Explorer. Good luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Internet Explorer (and Microsoft Edge, as of May 5, 2016) do not support native gripper/resizing on textarea elements. While these *may* eventually be supported in the future (in Microsoft Edge), the best option you have for now is to polyfill the functionality.

Many options exist online that do this, but if you're using jQuery and jQuery UI, you could use the [Resizable](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) widget:

```js
$("textarea").resizable({
    handles: "se" // place handle only in 'south-east' of textarea
});
```

By default, this places the handler beneath the textarea. I didn't like this:

```css
.ui-resizable-handle {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

You can see the end-result here: http://jsbin.com/rumokazepo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: As its not as good as builtin resize on capable browsers - how can I exclude script code for Firefox, Chrome etc. who already support CSS resize=both ?  (w/o dynamic server-side HTML generation)

Answer (score -8):

Can't this be solved in CSS by defining the `width` and `height` like so:

```
.resize {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
 }

 <textarea class="resize"></textarea>
```

Comment: Not really.  The question is about allowing the user to dynamically resize the textarea, not about setting a size to the textarea.